# Optimize insert of 1B+ rows

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, common-table-expression, large-data-volumes

I work in an organization that has over 75,000 employees.  In our payroll system, each employee has 32 unique banks which store things like Sick Time, Vacation Time, Banked Overtime, etc.

Here are the existing tables

```
Employee
(
   Employee_key INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   Lastname,
   Firstname
)

Employee Key | Lastname | Firstname
-----------------------------------
100          | Smith    | John

Bank
(
   Bank_key INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   Bank_name VARCHAR(50)
)

Bank_key  | Bank_name
---------------------
100       | VACATION


Employee_balance
(
  Employee_key INT, --FK to Employee
  Bank_key INT, --FK to Bank
  Bank_balance NUMERIC(10,5) -- Aggregate value of bank including future dated entries
)

Employee_key | Bank_Key | Bank_Balance
--------------------------------------
100          | 100      | 0


Employee_balance_trans
(
  Employee_key INT, --FK to Employee
  Bank_key INT, --FK to Bank
  Trans_dt DATE -- transaction date that affects the bank
  Bank_delta NUMERIC(10,5)  
)

Employee_key | Bank_key | Trans_dt | Balance_delta
--------------------------------------------------
100          | 100      | 20230701 | -8.0
100          | 100      | 20230801 | -8.0
100          | 100      | 20230901 | -8.0
100          | 100      | 20231001 | -8.0
100          | 100      | 20231101 | -8.0
```

This employee has 5 vacation days booked into the future, for a total of 40 hours.  As of January 1, the employee had 40 hours in their vacation bank, but because the employee_balance table is net of all future dated entries, I have to do some SQL processing to get the value for a current date.

```
SELECT  eb.employee_key, 
        eb.bank_key,
        '2023-01-01',
        eb.employee_balance - ISNULL(SUM(feb.balance_delta), 0)
FROM    employee a
INNER JOIN employee_balance eb on eb.employee_key = a.employee_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN wfms.employee_balance_trans ebt ON  ebt.balance_key = eb.balance_key
                                                AND ebt.employee_key = eb.employee_key
                                                AND ebt.trans_dt > '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY eb.employee_key, eb.balance_key, eb.employee_balance
```

Running this query using 2023-01-01 returns a bank value of 40 hours.  Running the query on 2023-07-01 returns a value of 32 hours and so on.  This query is fine for calculating a single employee balance.  The problem starts when a manager of a department with 1000 employees wants to see a report showing the employee banks at the beginning and end of each month.

I created a new table as follows:

```
Employee_bank_history
(
   employee_key INT, --FK to employee
   bank_key INT, --FK to bank
   bank_date DATE,
   bank_balance NUMERIC (10,5) -- Contains the bank balance as of the bank date
)
```

The table has a unique clustered index consisting of employee_key, bank_key and bank_date.  The table is also populated every evening with a date range from December 31 2021 to Current Date.  The start date gets reset every year, so there will be a maximum of 730 days worth of data.  This means that at the maximum date range of 730 days, there will be almost 2 billion rows. (75,000 employees X 32 banks X 730 days.)

Currently, I am loading 950 million rows, and the following INSERT statement takes 30-45 minutes.

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART (YY, GETDATE())-2, 12, 31)   
DECLARE @EndDate    DATE = GETDATE()
;

WITH cte_bank_dates AS
(   
    SELECT  [date]
    FROM    dim_date
    WHERE   [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)

INSERT INTO employee_balance_history
SELECT  de.employee_key, 
        deb.balance_key,
        cte.[date],
        deb.bank_balance - ISNULL(SUM(feb.bank_delta), 0)
FROM    employee de
INNER JOIN employee_balance deb on deb.employee_key = de.employee_key
CROSS JOIN cte_bank_dates cte
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_balance_trans feb  ON  feb.balance_key = deb.balance_key
                                                    AND feb.employee_key = deb.employee_key
                                                    AND feb.bank_date > cte.[date]
GROUP BY de.employee_key, deb.balance_key, cte.[date], deb.bank_balance
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I use the CTE to get only the dates in the correct range.  I need to have each date in the range, so that I know which future dates to exclude from the aggregate option.  The resulting query to get bank balances as of a given date is blazing fast.

Today, I had my hands slapped and was told that the CROSS JOIN to the CTE was not needed and to optimize the query because it was slowing everything else down when it runs.

Leaving aside the fact that it will run overnight once in production, I'm left to wonder if there's a better way to populate this table for every employee, every bank and every date.  The number of rows is unavoidable, as is the calculation to strip out future dated transactions from the employee bank balance.

Does anyone have any idea how I might make this faster, and less resource intensive on the server?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you empty the data set each day and repopulate it. However (once again if I'm reading this correctly) the vast majority of the data doesn't change - it's still the same as yesterday's data set - but also has today? As such, would it be possible to do it as simply adding today's data to yesterdays? Alternatively, if you do need to recalculate every day, you could process 1 day at a time, by getting the previous day's data then adding the current day (note your clustered indexes are then best started with the date field) - trying to avoid large GROUP BY

Comment: Stupid DBA tricks! You got your "hand slapped" without advice on how to proceed. That's not good  There's absolutely nothing wrong with CROSS JOINing a date table. Try this: run the SELECT part of this query, without the INSERT, in SSMS. If possible on a test copy of the database. Before you run it, right-click in the query window and select "Show Actual Execution Plan". Then after it runs, look at the execution plan. It may suggest an index to create. If so, do that and try again. At any rate, use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to show us the plan.

Comment: Thanks, seanb.  I will investigate this option if the DBA holds firm that my query must eliminate the use of the CROSS JOIN to a CTE which holds a date subset.

Comment: Thanks, O. Jones.  I've pasted the estimated plan here. 
 Don't want to run afoul of the DBA by running in full to get the actual plan. 
 https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r16GmZPoi